# Инсталлятор, создающий таблицы и данные из текстового sql-файла

Tags: php, mysql

"Необходимо создать пример работы динамических связанных выпадающих списков, создающихся на основе информации из базы данных MySQL. 
**Система должна иметь инсталлятор**, который при запуске создает таблицы и данные из текстового sql-файла. Доступы к базе данных должны храниться в конфигурационном файле."

Что значит "иметь инсталятор"? И если на компьютере не установлена MySQL, что тогда будет делать инсталятор? И если не установлен PHP, каким образом можно обращаться к базе с помощью PHP? 
Или я просто чего-то недопонимаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ИЛИ...**

Написать некий скрипт который проверяет существует ли соединение с БД. Если существует, проверить наличие условных таблиц в БД. Если таблицы отсутствуют, запустить инсталятор который найдет условный sql файл с дампом базы данных и выполнит запрос на установку таблиц!

Если нет практических или технических знаний в создании инсталяторов(вперед гуглить)!

Короче говоря это стандартная процедура любой коммерческой или некоммерческой CMS! Возмем любую бесплатную CMS типа <s>Joomla</s> или WP или... Все они имеют инсталятор! Логично?

Answer (score 2):

Нет. php и mysql изначально должны быть установлены.

Например: мы смотрим на конфигурацилнный файл, если он отсутсвует - то нужно запустить процесс инсталляции.

запускаем, проверяем можно ли записать в папку где должен лежать этот файл: если нельзя - выводим сообщение об ошибке (не могу записать в директорию такую-то) и в сессии запоминаем шаг, на котором мы застряли:

При обновлении страницы  смотрим наш флаг: и продолжаем с того места, на которой была ошибка. И так продолжается до тех пор пока не дадут права на запись нужной нам папки.

Потом просим ввести host, login, password, bd и прочеряем подключение с этими параметрами, если всё успешно - записываем конфигурационный файл и создаём таблици, sql которых указан в текстовом файле.